# TFS 2015 Determine which build agent is running the build

Tags: tfs, build, tfs-2015, build-agent

Scenario:

I have created an Agent pool and added/configured 2 build agent in it, which are installed on two different machines.
I have also enabled continuous integration.
When many developers check in the code, it triggers the build that I have queued.

Queries:

1. Whether the build will be assigned to most available build agent?
2. Is there any way to determine which build agent has built the code against a check-in?
3. How to setup the build controller? What is it's exact purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Whether the build will be assigned to most available build agent?

The build will be assigned to any of the online agents ie there is no concept of "most" or "more" available agent.

> Is there any way to determine which build agent has built the code against a check-in?

Yes, with a little digging. Get the build in which your commit was pushed to the repo. You can do this manually or write a program for this [using the REST apis](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview). The build logs will list the agent on which the build occurred.

> How to setup the build controller? What is it's exact purpose?

If you are using agent pools then you no longer need to setup a build controller. The build controller was used in the earlier versions of build to orchestrate the build across various build agents. Now with agents directly configured against the Team Foundation Server the build controller is no longer required.